# Combine four ID columns to one

Tags: sql-server-2008, bitstuffing

I have a view populated with data from 4 views. Now in the combined view I get four ID columns from each of the views with non-similar values. I need to get all them in a single Field (say ID_NEW).Can I proceed by stuffing? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ID_1)+' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ID_2)+' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ID_3)+' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ID_4) AS ID_NEW from CombinedView
```